# Is there a LINK_DIRECTORIES or equivalent property in CMake?

Tags: cmake

I have created a project with a large number of link_directories() commands. I'd now like to store the resulting string of directories into a variable. For include_directories() this is easy using

```
get_property( test_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES TARGET test PROPERTY INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES )
```

however there seems to be no LINK_DIRECTORIES property to do

```
get_property( test_LINK_DIRECTORIES TARGET test PROPERTY LINK_DIRECTORIES )
```

Is there a way to get a list of link directories used for a target?

(Note: I realize I could manually track the link directories in a variable myself and then use a single link_directories() but it doesn't seem very clean)

Comment: Why do you need the list as a variable?

Comment: I want to send these link directories "up" to a parent project so the parent project will link against the libraries specified in the child correctly. I will eventually get around to using absolute library paths and so completely avoid link_directories() but for now......

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Take a look at the [`LINK_DIRECTORIES` directory property](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/prop_dir/LINK_DIRECTORIES.html).

The point is that `link_directories` operates on a per-directory basis (the command affects all targets defined in the same CMakeLists, as well as targets from all of its subdirectories), unlike, for instance, `target_include_directories` which works on a per-target basis.

You can query the value of the property with:

```
get_property(test_LINK_DIRECTORIES DIRECTORY PROPERTY LINK_DIRECTORIES)
```

if called from the same directory as the `link_directories` call. Otherwise, you need to give the (full or relative) path as an additional argument after `DIRECTORY`. Unfortunately, I know of no way to obtain the matching directory for an existing target.

Note that in general the [use of `link_directories` is discouraged](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/command/link_directories.html) in CMake, which is probably the main reason why it's not supported very well. Unless you have very good reasons not to, you should always stick with full library paths passed to `target_link_libraries`. It will save you lots of headaches in the long run.

Comment: Thanks! In the linked doc the property is marked as for debugging use. Does this mean it may disappear?

Comment: @user2746401 I do not know of any such plans. The comment is probably referring to the fact that you can only set this property through `link_directories` and not by using `set_property`.

Comment: I'm now trying to use full library paths but am getting headaches with those. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25423905/platform-library-name-expansion-using-target-link-libraries-with-absolute-path-a