# Platform library name expansion using target_link_libraries with absolute path as library path?

Tags: cmake

Using target_link_libraries in CMake with just the library name, e.g.

```
target_link_library( myProject SomeLibrary )
```

will expand SomeLibrary to SomeLibrary.lib, libSomeLibrary.so, etc. depending on platform. However, if a full path is specified then the library name is not expanded based on platform, e.g.

```
target_link_library( myProject ${myProject_SOURCE_DIR}/libs/SomeLibrary )
```

How can I get the library name to be expanded based on platform? Currently, I'm detecting platform in the script and adjusting the library names myself which feels a little ugly.

(Background: over on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25164041/is-there-a-link-directories-or-equivilent-property-in-cmake) I'm advised to use absolute paths when specifying libraries rather than using link_directories)

Answer (score 2):

Use [`find_library`](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/command/find_library.html).

Instead of hardcoding the full path, you should only give the name of the library and a list of (possibly configurable) locations where it might be found and have `find_library` do the rest. If successful, the result of the `find_library` call can be fed right into `target_link_libraries`.